# Eclipse (Juno) error testing servlet with Tomcat7

Tags: eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I have been beating my head against a wall for 2 days regarding this issue so I finally decided I need to ask for some assistance.

I downloaded a tutorial from a popular site and import the `Maven` project to my `Eclipse` session.  I set up my `TomCat7` server and the project seems to build fine.  However when I go to run it on the server in `Eclipse` I get to the `index.jsp` page by when I try to move past that I get a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.mantiso.SimpleServlet
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


I did an `mvn package` and I manually deployed it to `tomcat7` and it works fine.  I am assuming that my ClassPath is missing something that prevents TomCat from finding the `SImpleServlet.class` file.  

Does anyone have any advice on debugging this?   

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Adding ClassNotFoundException and servlet code:

SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet SimpleServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mantiso.SimpleServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Servlet code
    package com.mantiso;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/home", "*.do"}, name="SimpleServlet", initParams = {@WebInitParam(name = "ProductName", value="Welcome Application")})
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;
    String appName = "My Application";

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        appName = getServletContext().getInitParameter("ProductName");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        if(name != null) {
            resp.setContentType("text/xml");
            resp.getWriter().printf("<application>" +
                    "<name>Hello %s</name>" +
                    "<product>%s</product>" +
                    "</application>", name, appName);
        } else {
            resp.getWriter().write("Please enter a name");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        if(name != null && name != ""){
            resp.getWriter().printf("Hello %s", name);
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `ClassNotFoundException` exception?

Comment: Sorry here is the exception and teh servlet code

Comment: is your project compiled with jdk7?